Prevent duplicates when filtering on prefetch_related
I have two models: Seller and Product.
Each product has a foreignKey to a seller. So each product only has one seller, but a seller can be related to many products.
This is the ForeignKey in my Product-Class:
seller = models.ForeignKey(
    Seller,
    on_delete=SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    related_name="products",
)

Now I try to query all Sellers and have the related products for each seller with them.
sellers = (
    Seller.objects.filter(
        ..doing some filtering
    ).prefetch_related("products").filter(products__branch=current_branch)
)

By doing this, my sellers has multiple entries for many sellers as I am filtering on the prefetche_related products resulting in a join inside the database-query.
What would be the best way to end up with a List of Sellers, each of them having their list of products with them? Without duplicates. I still need to filter on the products as I don't want all the products to be queried.

I'm not sure to understand what's wrong with having multiple entries for your sellers, since you can filter or order them as you need. And the concept of a "list" isn't really database-like, though you can process your queryset to get a Python list. Could you edit your question, with a sample of the expected output and / or what you need to do with that output ?
